# Extend class inside the WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate plugin

Tags: wordpress, class, extend, boilerplate

Does anyone know how to properly extend the main admin class inside this WP boilerplate plugin?

Simplified code:

admin/class-plugin-name-admin.php

```
class Plugin_Name_Admin { ... }
```

(custom) extended class:
admin/class-plugin-name-admin-custom.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

    if( ! class_exists('Plugin_Name_Admin') ) {
        require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'admin/class-plugin-name-admin.php';
    }

class Plugin_Name_Admin_Fields extends Plugin_Name_Admin {

// as a test I simply added an admin link
public function books_register_ref_page() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=books',
        __( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options',
        'books-shortcode-ref',
        'books_ref_page_callback'
    );
}

}
$fields = new Plugin_Name_Admin_Fields();
```

Then inside 
includes/class-plugin-name.php

I was hoping I could use the following hook

```
$plugin_admin = new Plugin_Name_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

$this->loader->add_action( 'admin_menu', $plugin_admin, 'books_register_ref_page' );
```

but instead I get a couple of errors

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Plugin_Name_Admin' does not have a method 'books_register_ref_page' in...
```

I know I can solve this by using this instead:

```
$plugin_extended = new Plugin_Name_Admin_Fields( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

$this->loader->add_action( 'admin_menu', $plugin_extended, 'books_register_ref_page' );
```

The problem is, am I understanding the `"Class X extend Main Class"` correctly in the first place? My goal is to not create one long file of code inside the

```
class Plugin_Name_Admin { ... }
```

Instead, I want to place some specific code inside a different class that **extends** the main `Plugin_Name_Admin` class.

If I have a function in the main class (`Plugin_Name_Admin`) that requires code inside the extended class, it should work out of the box without redefining the extended class first. Otherwise whats the use of "Class X extend Main Class"?